# Window and Menu IDs

Tags: applescript

There's a tool on OS X, and I can't remember what it is for the life of me, that will display what the menu and window IDs are of a selected tab, window, or checkbox. Can anyone refresh my memory?!

Comment: Are you thinking of [UI Browser](http://pfiddlesoft.com/uibrowser/) ?

Comment: it's not UI Browser. exactly the same idea, but free and I think it comes in the Developer Tools

Answer (score 4):

Are you thinking of [UIElementInspector](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/UIElementInspector/Introduction/Intro.html) ?

Comment: The version that comes bundled with *Xcode* is called *Accessibility Inspector*.